# Optimizing a inequality query in ndb over two properties

Tags: python, performance, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to do a query into a range of valid dates

```
q = Licence.query(Licence.valid_from <= today, 
                  Licence.valid_to >= today,
                  ancestor = customer.key               
                  ).fetch(keys_only=True)
```

I know that Datastore doesn't support inequality queries over two propperties. 
So I do this:

```
kl = Licence.query(Licence.valid_from <= today, 
                  ancestor = customer.key               
                  ).fetch(keys_only=True)
licences = ndb.get_multi(kl)
for item in licences:
    if item.valid_to < today:
        licence.remove(item)
```

But I don't like because I think that I use too much RAM retrieving more entities (or keys) from the Datastore that I finally need.

Any body knows a better way of doing this type of queries?

Is enough to use .filter() before .get()?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create a new field, like start_week, which buckets the queries and allows you to use an IN query to filter:

```
q = Licence.query(Licence.start_week in range(5,30),
                  Licence.valid_to >= today,
                  ancestor = customer.key)
```

Even simpler: Use a [projection query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#projection) to identify the right set of data without fetching full entities.  This is faster than a regular query.

```
it = Licence.query(License.valid_from <= today,
                   ancestor = customer.key
                   ).iter(projection=[License.valid_to])
keys = [e.key for e in it if e.valid_to >= today]
licenses = ndb.get_multi(keys)
```