# TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to DateProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, python-datetime

I am trying to query if a certain date belongs to a specific range of dates. Source code example:

```
billing_period_found = BillingPeriod.query(
        ndb.AND(
            transaction.date > BillingPeriod.start_date,
            transaction.date < BillingPeriod.end_date)
        ).get()
```

Data definition:

```
class Transaction(ndb.Model):
    date = ndb.DateProperty(required=False)

class BillingPeriod(ndb.Model):
    start_date = ndb.DateProperty(required=False)
    end_date = ndb.DateProperty(required=False)
```

Getting the following error:
TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to DateProperty

The message error does make sense because datetime is different from DateProperty. However, as you can see, the definition for transaction.date is not datetime, so I am not getting where this attempt to convert datetime to date is coming from. Anyways - If I figure out how to convert datetime to DateProperty, I guess it would fix the problem.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The App Engine datastore does not allow queries with inequalities on multiple properties (not a limitation of `ndb`, but of the underlying datastore). Selecting date-range entities that contain a certain date is a typical example of tasks that this makes it impossible to achieve in a single query.

Check out [Optimizing a inequality query in ndb over two properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22176586/optimizing-a-inequality-query-in-ndb-over-two-properties) for an example of this question, and, in the answer, one suggestion that might work: query for (in your case) all `BillingPeriod` entities with `end_date` greater than the desired date, perhaps with a projection to just get their key and `start_date`; then, select out of those only those with `start_date` less than the desired date, in your own application (if you only want one of them, then a `next` over the iterator will stop as soon as it finds one).

**Edit**: the issue above is problem #1 with this code; once solved, problem #2 arises -- as clearly listed at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries, the property is `ndb` queries is always on the *left* of the comparison operator. So, one can't do `date < BillingPeriod.end_date`, as that would have the property on the *right*; rather, one does `BillingPeriod.end_date > date`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Alex. I am still getting the same error after removing the AND condition. I think the issue is more related to the fact that gae is trying to converting datetime to dateproperty. It doesn't really make sense to me because all the comparison are based on DateProperty values coming from the datastore:
 billing_period_found = BillingPeriod.query(
                date < BillingPeriod.end_date
            ).get()

Comment: @FabioMoggi, look at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries, and I quote: "NDB supports these operations: property == value, property < value" etc; note that the property is always on the *left* of the comparison operator. So you can't do `date < BillingPeriod.end_date` as that would have the property on the *right*; rather, just do `BillingPeriod.end_date > date`. Putting this back up in my answer as well, for completeness.

Comment: Fantastic! It did work this time. Sorry for the lack of attention and thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Ma prego @FabioMoggi, mi scuso on my turn for not spotting issue #2 at the start and thus giving the complete answer from the beginning.